# Change template after user login in joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Anybody ever tried to change joomla 1.5 template in code? Don't know how to do it on current version. I just wanted to change the template after the user login.

So, i wrote code like this :

```
$mainframe->setTemplate('newtemplate');
```

But it doesn't works. WHen i see the joomla application.php, whoops, there is no setTemplate function there, but it used to be there before 1.5 (based on my search on the web). 
Anyone know how to do it?

Update :
seems that we can set user state and just read that user state, then render. But I don't know where joomla render the template, since I put a code in library/joomla/application.php, insite render(), but it didn't get executed. This is what i did :

```
function render()
{
    $params = array(
        'template'     => $this->getTemplate(),
        'file'        => 'index.php',
        'directory'    => JPATH_THEMES
    );

    // I added this code, where i set the user state $option.template somewhere else
    $template = $mainframe->getUserState( "$option.template", 'FoxySales01VIP' );
    if(!empty($template)){
        $params['template'] = $template;
    }

    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
    $data = $document->render($this->getCfg('caching'), $params );
    JResponse::setBody($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i solved it.

Just change the code in core library (JDocument Class) to read the template from session, works fine.

Thanks